# Data in <h:inputText readonly="true"> disappears when command button is clicked

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF 1.1. I have a JSF page with a request scoped bean and a readonly input field.

```
<h:inputText id="dt" value="#{bean.sdate}" readonly="#{bean.disable}" />
<a onclick="cal('dt');"><img src="fr.gif" border="0"></a>
```

When I set the input value using JavaScript and click on command button, then the data in input field disappears.

How is this caused and how can I solve it.

Comment: I know that some people answering question on SO may be considered magicians, but they can do nothing **without code sample**.

Comment: I really don't know what happens in `cal(some String variable)` method ...

Comment: if your readonly is set to true the value of #{bean.sdate} wont be sent to server... and thus get lost...

Comment: @Daniel: you're describing `disabled`, not `readonly`.

Comment: @BalusC it happened for readonly=true also :)

Comment: @Ajay: Wrong. Check Network panel in browser to see it yourself. HTML `disabled` won't send value. HTML `readonly` will send value. It's only that JSF itself skips processing of both. Taking a step back and learning some basic HTML before diving further deep in JSF wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: @BalusC yes you are correct JSF itself is skipping readonly=true

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's because the property is set to `readonly`. If this evaluates `true`, then JSF won't process the submitted value and hence the model won't be updated. If you want to set it to `readonly` on rendering the view **and** have JSF to process the submitted value, then you'd need to make it to evaluate `true` on render response phase only. You can use [`FacesContext#getRenderResponse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getRenderResponse%28%29) for this. You'd need to do this in your `isDisable()` method.

```
public boolean isDisable() { // TODO: rename to isReadonly().
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRenderResponse();
}
```

Note: in JSF2 you could access `FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()` by `#{facesContext}` in the view as well, this saves some boilerplate in the model:

```html
<h:inputText ... readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}" />
```

Also note that when you're using JSF2 `<f:viewParam>`, then this approach won't work on GET requests anymore. See also [Make a p:calendar readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639415/make-pcalendar-readonly/) for the explanation and workaround.

Comment: at the same time I was wondering if suppose I want to update the model at any other phase like "process validation" then how can I do the same like you did here.