# Make a p:calendar readonly

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to make [`<p:calendar>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml) readonly so that users can only choose a date from the calendar because of [this](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5626) issue (this is not a solution though).

For this to be so, I'm doing `readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}"` as mentioned by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10388648/1391249) answer like,

```
<p:calendar id="calendarId" 
        value="#{bean.property}" 
        converter="#{jodaTimeConverter}" 
        pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a" 
        showOn="button" 
        readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}" 
        effect="slideDown"
        required="true" 
        showButtonPanel="true" 
        navigator="true"/>
```

This works but when the page is loaded (typing the URL in the address bar and then pressing the enter key), `facesContext.renderResponse` returns `false` and the calendar is no longer readonly. It evaluates to `true`, when I submit the form by pressing `<p:commandButton>`.

So, how to make the calendar readonly, when the page is loaded?

P.S : I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5 and Mojarra 2.1.9.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The behavior has indeed changed since JSF 2.0. The [`FacesContext#getRenderResponse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getRenderResponse%28%29) only returns `true` if [`FacesContext#renderResponse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#renderResponse%28%29) is *explicitly* been called. Previously this happened during restore view phase of every GET request. However, since the introduction of `<f:viewParam>`, JSF will not do that anymore when at least one view parameter is present, it will just continue executing every single phase without skipping any phase in order to properly process the view parameters.

You apparently have a `<f:viewParam>` in your page. That's totally fine, but as a test, try removing it and you'll see that it returns `true` on a plain GET request as well.

You've basically 2 options to get around it:

1. Check the [`FacesContext#isPostback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29) as well. It always returns `false` on GET requests.

   ```html
   readonly="#{not facesContext.postback or facesContext.renderResponse}"
   ```
2. Check the [`FacesContext#getCurrentPhaseId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getCurrentPhaseId%28%29) instead. You only end up with uglier code (magic numbers).

   ```html
   readonly="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}"
   ```

   If you're using [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), you could make it less ugly.

   ```html
   <o:importConstants type="javax.faces.event.PhaseId" />
   ...
   readonly="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId eq PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE}"
   ```

Comment: this is very nice  solution :)