# How to use readonly and requirement together in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to use readonly and `require=true` in `inputtext`. However, `require` doesn't work with `readonly`. I tried some solution for example; `readonly="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}"` and `readonly="#{not facesContext.postback or facesContext.renderResponse}"`. These work the first time and then they doesn't work. What do I do for this situation?

```
<p:inputText value="#{userFilterBean.selectedData.fullName}" id="txtUser" readonly="true" required="true" styleClass="Wid100"/>
```

Comment: [Make a p:calendar readonly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17639554/1391249).

Comment: I use p:inputtext @Tiny

Comment: No difference in this case.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, please you explain this.

Comment: when you make an update to the composante does the readonly updated ?!?

Comment: I update to inputtext but they don't update component becase of readonly.

Answer (score 1):

you should use below

```
readonly="true" required="true"
```

to

```
readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}" required="true"
```

[Reference](http://ofarukkurt.blogspot.com.tr/2014/09/primefaces-inputtext-readonly-required.html)