# The class 'com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl' does not have the property 'currentPhaseId'

Tags: jsf

I have an xhtml file, where i want to perform readOnly, but after rendering the value for the field is not set. similar issues like this exist on SO. look up links below
[Make a p:calendar readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639415/make-a-pcalendar-readonly/17639554#17639554)

[JSF readonly inputText issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693205/jsf-readonly-inputtext-issue/18694415)

I have tried all suggestions from these links
here is my piece of code

```
                <h:outputLabel id="vatDeductionLabel" for="vatDeduction" value="Suma ubezpieczenia"/>
                <h:selectOneMenu id="vatDeduction" label="Suma ubezpieczenia" readonly="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}"
                                 value="#{DfeOper062MBean.dataModel.dfeOper062DataModel.requestParameters.vatDeduction}">
                </h:selectOneMenu>
```

now without readonly it works,but i need to set it to either disabled after rendering and setting value or read only.
when i try the above code using either facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6  or facesContext.renderResponse.

i get the error in my log

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/operations/dfeoper062/dfeOper062.xhtml @100,130 readonly="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}": The class 'com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl' does not have the property 'currentPhaseId'.
```

Any suggestion as to how to handle this situation? thank you

POM jsf version

```
   <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.15</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: What is your JSF version? What is your EL version?

Comment: According to [the javadoc](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getCurrentPhaseId--) that method was available since version 2.0. This exception clearly means that you're using an older version.

Comment: @BalusC: That is what I suspected too, but if I remember correctly. I've seen an EL related issue where the EL did not resolve correctly from an abstract class (or an interface, not sure)

Comment: @Kukeltje: happens only on interface default methods, you'd need method invocation instead, but this is here not the case.

Comment: @Kukeltje i hava updated my task to show my version in pom file

Comment: @BalusC i am using 1.1.5 for jsf, its a legacy project and im not allowed to upgrade the version, what could be another solution

Comment: You are not allowed to update a very insecure system but you are allowed (required) to change this very old system? I'd give the assigment back to my superior... ;-) (and the version you post is the facelets version, not the JSF version)

Comment: @Kukeltje i have corrected the maven version in my post to jsf , and yes :) i understand , its would break the system to upgrade the version, as it is very huge,

Comment: Would there be another way to do this without upgrading versions ? may be without using current PhasId or response  in read only  @Kukeltje

Comment: Maybe create a phaselistener and in it add/set a variable with the phaseId on the requestContext and use that in the page? Or extend the FacesContext with your own or ...